# To Find if a Number is Armstrong in java(BlueJ)

Tags: java

A class HiArm has been defined to find whether a given number is an Armstrong number or not.

> **Armstrong number** is a number that is equal to the sum of cubes of its
>   digits for example 0, 1, 153, 370, 371, 407 etc.

Member functions:

- HiArm() - constructor to assign 0 to n
- HiArm(int a) - constructor to assign a to n
- int sumArm() - to find and return the sum of the cube of the digits of the number
- void isArm() - to invoke sumArm() and print if the number is Armstrong

write the main() method to input a number and call the above functions

Ps:- My approch:-

```
import java.util.*;
class HiArm{
    int n;
    int d;
    int b;
    int c;
    int g=n;
    HiArm(){
        n=0;
    }

    HiArm(int a){
        n=a;
    }

    int sumArm(){
        d = (int)(Math.log10(n) + 1);
        c=0;
        b=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=d;i++){
            b=g%10;
            b=b*b*b;
            c=c+b;  
            g=(g-(g%10))/10;
        }
        return c;
    }

    void isArm(){
        sumArm();
        if(c==n){
            System.out.println("The number is Armstrong");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The number is not Armstrong");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check whether it is an Armstrong or not");
        int k=sc.nextInt();
        HiArm o = new HiArm(k);
        o.isArm();        
    }
}
```

The function `sumArm()` always returns 0. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What is the error you get? What is your expected output?

Comment: What is not working ? You get an error ? You don't get the expected result ? BTW: making `sumArm()` returning a value, and then use the instance var. `c` is bad style. You should avoid side-effects. All this b,c,g,... should not be instance var. but local var. of the method. Same bad style naming applies to `isArm()`.

Comment: Fields are initialised before the constructor is called, so `g` will always be equal to 0. You need to set `g=a` in your `HiArm(int a)` constructor.

Comment: Please read [What do you mean "It Doesn't Work"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @teppic. I did as you said. But still, the same message appears

Comment: This will only work for three digit numbers (it won't match _1634_, for example). You need to change `b=b*b*b;`  to `b = (int) Math.pow(b, d);`.

Comment: @teppic nope, this is not the definition of an Amstring number, it's sum of the cubes, so b=b*b*b will always work, or Math.pow(b,3)

Comment: @azro: It's not the sum of the cubes. It's the sum of the digits raised to the power of the number of digits. 1634 is an Armstrong number.

Comment: @teppic .. sorry, to verify i open the first <ebsite and it said "to the cube" but i didn't see the "for the number of 3 digits" sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes on your code, let me explain ;)
import java.util.*;
class HiArm{

```
int value;
int sum;

HiArm(){
    value=0;
}

HiArm(int a){
    value=a;
}

int sumArm(){
    sum=0;
    for(char digit : String.valueOf(value).toCharArray()){
        sum += Math.pow(Integer.valueOf(digit)-48, String.valueOf(value).toCharArray().length);
    }
    return sum;
}

boolean isArm(){
    sumArm();
    /*
    if(sum==value){
        System.out.println("The number is Armstrong");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The number is not Armstrong");
    }
    */
    return sum==value;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number to check whether it is an Armstrong or not");
    int k=sc.nextInt();
    HiArm o = new HiArm(k);
    System.out.println(o.isArm());        
}
```

}

So first your error : initialization or your g was made BEFORE the constructor so its value was null
Then I allow me to change the names of parameters, you better do like this everytime to quickly know which parameter is doing what
Then I made a loop on each digit, I transform the value into a String, then in a array of char and I iterat over it, for each one I calculate digit^3 and add it to the sum (the "-48" is because of their ASCII code"),

Comment: I had two doubts:- 1) isArm() has to be of the form void isArm(), so how would the coding change for that. 2) In my program, I declared g=n inside sumArm() but the same error occurs

Comment: @Lucifer- 1) so just replace the word "boolean" by "void", erase the line "return sum==value", delete the '/* ' and ' */' and in the main method just write "o.isArm()" without the system.out.print ;)
2) If you use what i wrote you need intermediate variables, look you had 5, i have 2 ;) but if you want to try with g=n, write it juste before the "for" loop and it will normally work

Answer (score 0):

The Reason why it failed was cause `g` is assigned to `n` even before the constructor is called and is always `0`.

reassigning the variable `g` to `n` within the `sumArm()` function would fix the problem.

```
int sumArm(){
    d = (int)(Math.log10(n) + 1);
    c=0;
    b=0;
    g=n
    for(int i=1;i<=d;i++){
        b=g%10;
        b=b*b*b;
        c=c+b;  
        g=(g-(g%10))/10;
    }
    return c;
}
```